# How do I add more than one widget configuration activity in Android?

Tags: android, configuration, android-activity, android-intent, widget

I would like to add a [configuration activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring) for each widget size in my app. I thought I could just tag both in the manifest with an intent filter for the config activity and then give each their own configuration activity in each widget provider, but it's not working. I'll post some of my code.

Widget Provider 1 for a 2x1 widget and I want it to call the ConfigurationSmall activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_2_1"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5400000"
    android:configure="com.usethetriforce.heartcontainer.ConfigurationSmall"/>
```

Widget Provider 1 for a 4x1 widget and I want it to call the ConfigurationLarge activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="292dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_4_1"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5400000"
    android:configure="com.usethetriforce.heartcontainer.ConfigurationLarge" />
```

My Android Manifest looks something like this:

```
<activity
     android:name=".ConfigurationSmall"
     android:label="@string/menu_item_settings">
          <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
     android:name=".ConfigurationLarge"
     android:label="@string/menu_item_settings">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Any help would be most grateful.

Comment: I guess no one else knows either. :P

Comment: I am completely open to finding a workaround or another way to do this.